# SQL - Adding multiple values in 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add multiple values of a join query in 1 single column. Is there any way to do that?

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90540/1

Here is a screen of how to result should be like
  http://i60.tinypic.com/5pk7yg.png "result"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Did you mean "Concatenate"? Adding is an arithmetic operation and does not require anything else than the + operator in the query.

Comment: No not concatenate, the return of the query should be an array with all the information of both tables together in 1 array

Comment: can you add your required output to the question? not everyone can access public storage urls. it sounds like you just need a `union`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the problem, I (and many people here, I believe) doesn't have a clue what's a point of this query, what the goal you want to achieve with this.

To get desired result you can do something like this...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN p.id END AS col1,
       CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN p.`value` END AS col2,
       CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN (SELECT id FROM site_gender WHERE id = 2) END AS col3, 
       CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN (SELECT `value` FROM site_gender WHERE id = 2) END AS col4,
       a.id, a.email 
FROM site_gender AS p
JOIN user_account AS a ON p.id = a.id
```

but this query doesn't have a much sense, you'll get desired result but i don't know what you can do else with it.

here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90540/27) for that to see what's happend there...

But if you change a little your table **site_gender** and add her a column, let's call it **parent**, than you will have query like this

```
SELECT p.id, p.value, x.id, x.value, a.id, a.email 
FROM site_gender AS p
INNER JOIN site_gender AS x
ON p.id = x.parent
JOIN user_account AS a 
ON p.id = a.id
```

Here is [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05fe7/12) to see how that's look like and work...

point of having **parent** column is that you can choose which 2 column you want to connect when you have larger table so parent column will store id of column with that column should be connected...

If you have any further question fill free to ask!

GL!

Comment: You are awesome, that is what I needed, Thanks! What I am trying to archieve is to avoid looping in 2 queries, let me show a example: http://pastebin.com/uB5MjAds

Comment: You're welcome :) If you find this answer useful pleas vote it up :) I'm not quiet sure what your previous question have with this one in the comment, for me that's complete different question so it would be good to ask new question so everybody can see it and try to help you... GL

Comment: Also, about your question in comment above i think there is no need to have table age_option, i think that it's not good solution, you have age column in user_account table and to have separate table for age option i don't see the point of that... Age option you can store in PHP as an array or something like that and use it. There is definitely no reason to go in database to take that value form there.

Comment: I love to vote up but can't, but I need 15 votes myself to vote someone else. I will create a new question indeed to make it more understandable, which is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243749/sql-php-reduce-optimize-queries

Comment: Well now your question have more sense :) and everybody else will see it which is much better... about my answer you mark it as accepted that's great tnx for that... GL